# Tabs in navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I have Navigation drawer. I want to have tabs inside the navigation drawer, and changing the tab will change the content of navigation drawer (the fragment) not the main frame,[image]

Any Idea?
As you can see from the picture. My tabs will be CFS Details, And Search, etc... 
when navigate tabs it change the left Drawer not the Main Frame

Answer (score -1):

Yes... you have to use a fragment for every button from your navigation drawer.
Here is a nice **video tutorial**: [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwqzhY5i2rc)
And here you have **text tutorial:**  [developer tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
Second **text tutorial:** [tutorial 2](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html)

The second one is very nice explained!

Good luck!

Comment: I dont want to change the Main Frame content, I want to change the Left Drawer content as in the picture I added.